# Android app not seen on the emulator

Tags: android, titanium

I created the smallest Android app on Android 2.3.3 using Titanium. There is no error on the code, when the emulator loads i don't see my app on the phone. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: perhaps you could provide your trace output. would be helpful too.

Comment: I got it to work! There was some problem with the SDK config. Thanks for the Concern Balaji and mkind :)

Comment: What was de config problem?